# Dynamically handle email attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, smtp, email-attachments

I am working on local smtp server, I am using asp.net MVC and ATM I am storing all the email attachments on the server. The email comes, it's main content is being saved into one table as text and attachemtns are being saved on the server locally, and path to that file would be saved into DB table as a text. Then on the front end I open file specifying it's location. I am wondering if there are any other ways of dynamically handle the attachemnts, so I wouldn't need to save them on the server.

Comment: Attachments are in the body of an html message.  Not sure why your server is extracting the attachments and putting into a separate file. Some webpage (which use html pages) store a flat html format where a sub-directory is created that contains children of the page.  or you could just put the entire message along with attachments into a single file.

Comment: It does save it separately, because I handle it that way myself, because I thought it's the right way to do it. Because I need all the emails to be listed and attachments to be opened at any time. Do you mean that html body of the email stores attachment? Where do you suggest keeping that single file?

Comment: Each attachment is in a separate body of a single html message.  If you need to access the attachments at any time then you parse everything into a folder or store then html as a single file (MHT).  Try manually saving a email (using SaveAs) for outlook in MHT and then open the MHT with notepad to see the format.

Comment: But as I understand the HMT file still needs to be stored somewhere? and I am not sure how would use MHT file as my application view

Comment: I cannot answer the question WHERE TO STORE.  This is a design issues and I know nothing about your requirements.  Nor do I know how you plan on viewing the emails when you need to open.  The email response is HTML format (or text or RTF).  I also do not know if all the emails are going to be HTML.  You have to do the design work, we can only give answers to questions and some advice.

Comment: That's the main question I am asking, how to design it so I do not have to store file physially. But thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: You can always create a pst file to archive the emails, or save the emails as msg format which you can open in outlook. So you have an option of 4 formats 1) pst 2) msg 3) HTML 4) MHT